# Ruby on Rails How To send email with attachment using simple_form and mail_form gem. I do receive the email but there is nothing attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I'm trying to send an email with attachment using simple_form and mail_form gem but it's not working.

I used:

```
<%= simple_form_for @payment, html: { multipart: true }, defaults: 
{ wrapper_html: { class: 'form-group' }, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } } do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.file_field :file %>

<% end %>
```

I receive the email but there is nothing attached.

**Email`s Body**

Name: John

Email: test@email.com

Message: Testing email

File: #ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fc9094557c0

This is my Model

```
class Payment < MailForm::Base
attribute :name
attribute :cell_phone
attribute :user_code
attribute :email,    validate: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :message
attribute :file
attribute :nickname, captcha: true

def headers
    {
      subject: "Comprovante - Contas Atecorp",
      to: "email@email.com",
      from: %("Contas Atecorp" <email@email.com>),
      reply_to: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

And this is my Controller

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
    @payment.request = request
    if @payment.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
      redirect_to user_faturas_path(current_user)
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      redirect_to user_faturas_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  private

  def payment_params
    params.require(:payment).permit(:name, :email, :message, :nickname,
                                        :cell_phone, :user_code, :file)
  end
end
```

Comment: show us your attachment method

Comment: I don't have an attachment method. Should I create one?

Comment: then where do you specify the attachment to go with the email?

Comment: Try to add this to the header method "add_file :filename => 'somefile.png', :content => File.read('/filename.png')" or "attachments['filename.jpg'] = File.read('/path/to/filename.jpg')"

Comment: @olucube thanks for your help! I figured out the solution and it was ridiculous! It was just missing this: "attribute :file,  ***attachment: true***